# How do I change the class on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I'm working on a code snippet for a website and I want to change the class on click, it has to do with the mute button for the YouTube video,

Here is my code:

```
    // Sound volume


$('#mute-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var mute_toggle = $(this);

    if(player.isMuted()){
        player.unMute();
        mute_toggle.text('volume_up');
    }
    else{
        player.mute();
        mute_toggle.class('fa fa-volume-off');
    }
});

$('#volume-input').on('change', function () {
    player.setVolume($(this).val());
});
```

you'll see that the "mute_toggle" is a Font Awesome Icon,I want it to change from a fa-volume-up to a fa-volume-off on click,before I changed it,it was .text,which would be using the google fonts material icons as the text would change and the icon too.

How do I change the class using JavaScript on click using the code above?
From fa fa-volume-up (default) to fa fa-volume-off.

It must be used in this because it is using the YoutubeFrame API that controls the volume,playing,time, ect. However if you know a workaround this it would be most helpful.

Comment: Did you check jquery addClass & removeClass functions?

Comment: mute_toggle.addClass('fa-volume-off'')

Comment: I'll look into it,I haven't used jquery before,or coded it from scratch,always using templates or code snippets.

Comment: I wrote how to add class, same idea with remove.. Google 'jquery addclass' for more info/snippet

Comment: Thanks,it worked just fine.

Comment: Can you mark the question with green v so ill get my reputation pls?

Comment: I mean mark as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check jquery addClass & removeClass functions?

Comment: Working just fine,hope I don't ask another stupid question like this,thanks for the fast answer,I'll check the answer in a few minutes,final code here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JGWsNL29

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#mute-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var mute_toggle = $(this);

    if(player.isMuted()){
        player.unMute();
        mute_toggle.text('volume_up');
    }
    else{
        player.mute();
        mute_toggle.addclass('fa-volume-off'); 

  /* this adds class where #mute_toggle, also you need to add manually .fa class  */
  /*** or add this line to your code  ***/

  /*    mute_toggle.addclass('fa');   */


    }
});

$('#volume-input').on('change', function () {
    player.setVolume($(this).val());
});
```